# TestCafe can not get elements in userVariables

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I have a `.testcaferc.js` as below

```js
module.exports = {
    userVariables: {
        stress_test_num_rep: 200,
    }
}
```

and some simple code to test it

```js
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises";
const { userVariables } = require('testcafe');
const num_rep = userVariables.stress_test_run_rep;
```

I set a breakpoint below this code block, the `userVariables` is correct, it's `{ stress_test_num_rep: 200, }` but `num_rep` is `undefined`

However, what's more interesting is if I evaluate `userVariables.stress_test_run_rep` several times in debug console (VSCode), it's value will appear.

I want to get this `num_rep`, how could I do it? From the [official example](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402638/reference/configuration-file#user-variables) this should not be an async method, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a spelling mistake. 'userVariables' has a 'stress_test_**num**_rep' property, but you try to get the 'stress_test_**run**_rep' property.

Comment: Yeah... I feel so bad that I posted this question...

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises";
const { userVariables } = require('testcafe');
const num_rep = userVariables.stress_test_run_rep;
console.log(num_rep); // Now it will print 200
```

Comment: I ran your code, the console prints `undefined`